# display mulitple copies of page.aspx in one main page

Tags: asp.net

Just need an idea of what to do here. (beginner)

I have a web page, an ASDF.aspx.  It displays information.  Works just fine; has data bound controls ….  What I want to do is create a main review page, a  page that will display multiple copies of ASDF.aspx.

I don’t even know how to start.  In the old world, I’d create an object returning HTML ASDF text, call that object multiple times for each ASDF form I wanted to show, and then cat it all together.

Answer (score 1):

you can transfer all the logic from the aspx page to a .ascx web user control (should be pretty much a copy/paste). Then you can put one copy of your web user control in ASDF.aspx and multiple copies of your web user control in your review page.

A web user control is a naming container (so it will make sure all the controls have unique names in your review page). This will make sure your server-side logic still works, but you may have to check if you're referring to your controls by name in your client-side (javascript) logic, because the names the controls have in the HTML may change.

Comment: Within the User Control, you can add a public property which you can then use to handle the `id` which you are passing through in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

**Using a [web user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is the best practice to create reusable parts of a page.**

BTW, if you can't change the asdf.aspx page, as a workaround, you can use iframe. Put an iframe for each copy of asdf.aspx you want to show:

```
  <iframe src="asdf.aspx?id=1" />
  <iframe src="asdf.aspx?id=2" />
  <iframe src="asdf.aspx?id=3" />
```

Comment: I think user controls would be a better solution here. Obviously, OP is fairly new to .NET, and we should be showing him/her how to do it the way they're supposed to be done.

Comment: you're right. I made the assumption that the OP can't change the ASPX page. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

That's what user controls (ASCX files) are for. Take the markup and code-behind logic from ASDF.aspx and put it into a user control. Then, from the review page add multiple instances of the user control to the page.